# Singleton Route running in Cluster for Messaging Consumer w/ Quartz and RoutePolicies

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to have a singleton cluster configuration with only one messaging consumer route running in the cluster (if it matters it's a rabbitmq consumer).

I've configured Quartz and am using the clustered features, which seems to only work for having only one concurrent execution.

Also to note:  I've looked at using both the SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy and CronRoutePolicy.  The issue I'm seeing there is I'm not seeing a way to set the quartz endpoint parameters for quartz.  (stateful=true, JobName, GroupName etc...).

Am I doing something wrong here?  I apologize, as I'm a bit new to both camel and quartz.  Below is the route code to outline what i'm trying to do:

```
SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy policy = new SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000L;
policy.setRouteStartDate(new Date(startTime));
policy.setRouteStartRepeatCount(-1);
policy.setRouteStartRepeatInterval(10000);

from({consumer.endpoint}}").noAutoStartup().routePolicy(policy).to("log:example?showBody=true&multiline=false");
```

Comment: Where is your quartz endpoint here?

Comment: Well, that might be sort of the misunderstanding by me.  Given that i'm trying to do a messaging consumer, I don't have the quartz consumer defined.  Is there a way that I can use a messaging endpoint and quartz endpoint in tandem?

Comment: So, your route should triggered via quartz and then consume a message from rabbitmq? Yes that is possible.

Comment: Ideally, I'm using quartz for the locking.  I'd like to just have the messaging consumer up and running.  I wanted Quartz to basically just control weather or not the message route is started or not.  Is this still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0/5+12-18+?+*+MON-FRI").enrich("rabbitmq://<yourRabbitMQuri>).to("somewhere");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason behind limiting the application to one message consumer? Each processing step you add to a Camel route should be stateless.
I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements, so here's a general hint.

Camel offers JMS support out of the box, and [JMS Queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Elements) may be what you are looking for:

> **JMS queue**
>   A staging area that contains messages that have been sent and are waiting to be read (by only one consumer). Contrary to what the name queue suggests, messages don't have to be received in the order in which they were sent. A JMS queue only **guarantees that each message is processed only once**.

Your route could be something like:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:myqueue" />
    <log message="Received message: ${body}" />
    <to uri="bean:yourProcessorHere" />
</route>
```

[ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) is also supported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm afraid that rabbitmq is a requirement for me with this consumer.  I guess the reason I don't want 2 consumers is because I don't want the messaging consumer to be scheduled.  Again, i'm only trying to use quartz as a way to prevent the a cluster environment from competing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use another [Camel route policy](http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html). Camel comes with support for a Zookeeper based route policy (http://camel.apache.org/zookeeper.html). In such a solution Zookeeper would elect the active node.

If you don't want to build up the necessary Zookeeper infrastructure, you could roll your own route policy and use a database to do the election of the active node by having your nodes compete to lock a table row, have a look [here](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/11/11/Hot+Standby+failover+for+Apache+Camel+routes) and [here](https://github.com/cschneider/simplecluster) for inspiration. Be aware the code might be outdated. Could be a starting point though.